# How to choose LinearSVC instead of SVC if kernel=linear in param_grid?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I have the following way to create the grid_cv_object. Where `hyperpam_grid={"C":c, "kernel":kernel, "gamma":gamma, "degree":degree}`.

```
grid_cv_object = GridSearchCV(
        estimator = SVC(cache_size=cache_size),
        param_grid = hyperpam_grid,
        cv = cv_splits,
        scoring = make_scorer(matthews_corrcoef), # a callable returning single value, binary and multiclass labels are supported
        n_jobs = -1, # use all processors
        verbose = 10,
        refit = refit
    )
```

Here kernel can be `('rbf', 'linear', 'poly')` for example.

How can I enforce the selection of LinearSVC for the 'linear' kernel? Since this is embedded in `hyperparam_grid` I'm not sure how to create this sort of "switch".

I just don't want to have 2 separate grid_cv_objects if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making parameter grids in the following form

```py
from sklearn.dummy import DummyClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

search_spaces = [
    {'svm': [SVC(kernel='rbf')],
     'svm__gamma': ('scale', 'auto'),
     'svm__C': (0.1, 1.0, 10.0)},
    {'svm': [SVC(kernel='poly')],
     'svm__degree': (2, 3),
     'svm__C': (0.1, 1.0, 10.0)},
    {'svm': [LinearSVC()],  # Linear kernel
     'svm__C': (0.1, 1.0, 10.)}
]
svm_pipe = Pipeline([('svm', DummyClassifier())])
grid = GridSearchCV(svm_pipe, search_spaces)
```

Discussion:

1. We separate different kernels with different instances of `SVC`. This way, `GridSearchCV` will not estimate, say, `SVC(kernel='poly')` with different `gamma`s, which are ignored for `'poly'` and are designated only for `rbf`.
2. As you request, `LinearSVC` (and in fact any other model), not `SVC(kernel='linear')`, is separated to estimate a linear svm.
3. Best estimator will be `grid.best_estimator_.named_steps['svm']`.

Comment: This looks amazing! But how do I pass this to GridSearchCV? Would it be estimator= svm_pipe? Without passing any param_grid?

Comment: @Caterina `GridSearchCV(estimator=svm_pipe, param_grid=search_spaces)`

Comment: But @SanjarAdilov in the [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) it says that gamma is used for all but linear?

`gamma{‘scale’, ‘auto’} or float, default=’scale’. Kernel coefficient for ‘rbf’, ‘poly’ and ‘sigmoid’."`